# How to generate multiple simulation paths in survival analysis forecasting?

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, forecasting, survival

I am trying to create R code for generating multiple simulation paths for forecasting survival probabilities. In the code posted at the bottom of this post, I take the `survival` package's `lung` dataset and create a new dataframe `lung1`, representing the `lung` data "as if" the study max period were 500 instead of the 1022 it actually is in the `lung` data. I use a parametric Weibull distribution per goodness-of-fit tests I ran separately. I'm trying to forecast, via multiple simulation paths, survival curves for periods 501-1000 using, ideally as a random number generation guide the Weibull parameters for the data for periods 1-500. This exercise is a forecasting "what-if", if I only had data for a 500-period lung study. I then compare the forecasts with the actual lung data for periods 501-1000.

The shape and scale parameters I extracted from the `lung1` data are 1.804891 and 306.320693, respectively.

I'm having difficulty generating reasonable, monotonically decreasing simulation paths for forecast periods 501-1000. In looking at the code posted at the bottom, what should I be doing instead?

The below images help illustrate:

1. First image is a K-M plot showing survival probabilities for the entire lung dataset.
2. Second image plots lung1 (500 assumed study periods) with period 501-1000 forecasts extending in grey lines. Obviously something is not quite right!
3. Third image is only there to show simulations I've done in the past before using time-series models such as ETS, which sort of gets at what I'm trying to do here with survival analysis. This isn't my best example, I've generated nice monotonically decreasing, concave forecast curves using log transformations and ETS. I am now trying to understand survival analysis better, no more ETS for now.

[image]

Code:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(MASS)

# Modify lung dataset as if study had only lasted 500 periods
lung1 <- lung %>% 
  mutate(time1 = ifelse(time >= 500, 500, time)) %>% 
  mutate(status1 = ifelse(status == 2 & time >= 500, 1, status))

fit1 <- survfit(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)

# Get survival probability values at each time point
surv_prob <- summary(fit1, times = seq(0, 500, by = 1))$surv

# Create a data frame with time and survival probability values
lungValues <- data.frame(Time = seq(0, 500, by = 1), Survival_Probability = surv_prob)

# Plot the survival curve using the new data frame
plot(lungValues$Time, lungValues$Survival_Probability, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Survival Probability",
     main = "Survival Plot", type = "l", col = "blue", xlim = c(0, 1000), ylim = c(0, 1))

# Generate correlation matrix for Weibull parameters
cor_matrix <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

# Generate simulation paths for forecasting
num_simulations <- 10
forecast_period <- seq(501, 1000, by = 1)
start_prob <- 0.293692
shape <- 1.5
scale <- 100

for (i in 1:num_simulations) {
  # Generate random variables for the Weibull distribution
  random_vars <- mvrnorm(length(forecast_period), c(0, 0), Sigma = cor_matrix)
  shape_values <- exp(random_vars[,1])
  scale_values <- exp(random_vars[,2]) * scale
  
  # Calculate the survival probabilities for the forecast period
  surv_prob <- numeric(length(forecast_period))
  surv_prob[1] <- start_prob
  for (j in 2:length(forecast_period)) {
    # Calculate the survival probability using the Weibull distribution
    surv_prob[j] <- pweibull(forecast_period[j] - 500, shape = shape_values[j], scale = scale_values[j], lower.tail = FALSE)
    # Ensure the survival probability follows a monotonically decreasing, concave path
    if (surv_prob[j] > surv_prob[j-1]) {
      surv_prob[j] <- surv_prob[j-1] - runif(1, 0, 0.0005)
    }
  }
  
  # Combine the survival probabilities with the forecast period and create a data frame
  df <- data.frame(Time = forecast_period, Survival_Probability = surv_prob)
  
  # Add the simulation path to the plot
  lines(df$Time, df$Survival_Probability, type = "l", col = "grey")
}
```

Comment: Aren't you conflating your estimates of population level survival at time t (your Weibull distribution parameters) with the probability of survival beyond time t at the level of the idividual?  My approach to this problem would be to simulate survioval at the patient level and then calculate the population level survival estimates.  Once for each simulation.  [Does your "other dataset" example use your methodology or is it an example plucked from the literature?]

Comment: In response to your [question], the other dataset is non-public monthly data for patients where each month (for each patient) is coded 0 if alive and 1 upon death. I plopped the data into ETS model and other time-series models for quick and easy curve extrapolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the logic of your code very difficult to follow, so I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but it seems reasonable to me.

My starting point is your `lung1` data frame.

First, fit a Weibull ditsribution to your data and obtain the fitted estimates of `shape` and `scale`.  Note that `survreg` and `rweibull` use different parameterisations.

```
wFit <- survreg(Surv(time1,status1)~1, dist="w", data=lung1)

# See online doc for survreg for explanation
scale <- exp(wFit$coefficients[1])
shape <- 1/wFit$scale
median(rweibull(2000, shape, scale))
[1] 326.3782
```

[`survfit` reports a median of 310.]

Now, write a function to impute survival times for survival beyond time 500 and then derive a Kaplan-Meier estimate of the survival distribution.  The function takes a single parameter, `x`.  If `x` is `1`, Estimated survival probabilities for time < 500 are included in the return value, otherwise, they are not.

```
# Generate simulation paths for forecasting
num_simulations <- 10
start_prob <- 0.293692

simulate <- function(x=1) {
  lung2 <- lung1 %>% 
    mutate(
      time2 = ifelse(
                time > 500, 
                qweibull(runif(nrow(.), min=1-start_prob), shape, scale), 
                time
              ),
      # It's possible that some simulated survival times are *just* under 500
      status2 = ifelse(time == 500, 2, status)
    )
  summary2 <- summary(survfit(Surv(time2, status2) ~ 1, data = lung2))
  result <- tibble(Simulation=x, Time=summary2$time, Survival=summary2$surv) %>% 
    add_row(Simulation=x, Time=0, Survival=1, .before=1)
  if (x == 1) {
    return(result %>% mutate(Type=Time > 500))
  } 
  return(result %>% filter(Time > 500) %>% add_column(Type=TRUE))
}
```

Now use the function to simulate survival times > 500 several times.  Bind the results into a single data frame.

```
simulations <- lapply(1:num_simulations, simulate) %>% bind_rows()
```

Plot the results.

```
simulations %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(x=Time, y=Survival, group=interaction(Simulation, Type), colour=Type)
  ) +
  geom_step(show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "grey"))
```

[image]

I hope that helps.

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for. And this gives me even more confidence in the NHS!

Comment: Do you know if the `survreg()` function you used accounts for uncertainty in the shape and scale parameters? If not, how difficult would it be to draw from distributions of the shape and scale values consistent with the variance-covariance matrix of their modeled estimates, for example with `mvrnorm()` function of the R MASS package?

Comment: Also do you see much value in penalizing the Weibull regression (and complicating the code further) with something like `fit <- survreg(Surv(time, has_event) ~ 1 + ridge( predictor1, predictor2, ... , theta=1, scale=T), dist = "weibull", data=...)`, where the ridge-penalty theta is picked using cross-validation?

Comment: The `survereg` function isn't the source of the random variation in my code, though you can get parameter variances from it.  The variation in my code comes from `qweibull(runif(nrow(.), min=1-start_prob), shape, scale)`.  You could adapt my code so that `shape` and `scale` are random, rather than constants.  How to do that, and your question about penalised analysis, are too deep for here, IMHO, and probably even for CrossValidated.  I suggest you seek advice within your institution.  But I am happy to have helped with the basics.

Comment: See the below Cross Validated post for insights into accounting for uncertainty in shape and scale parameters of the Weibull distribution: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/614198/how-to-generate-multiple-forecast-simulation-paths-for-survival-analysis